# Initialize postgres with data-checksums

Tags: postgresql, redhat

I'm trying to enable PostgreSQL 9.6 og Redhat 7 with data-checksums enabled. According to the doc you can run initdb either with the -k flag or --data-checksums. But when I try to run `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb --data-checksums` it does not work.
Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

don't use postgresql96-setup

execute it like: ( it work :)

```
./initdb -k  -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data
postgres=# show data_checksums;
 data_checksums
----------------
 on
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about RH tools but `-k` is an option to `initdb` not `postgresql96-setup`.

To initialize data directory using native PostgreSQL tools:

```
su - postgres
locale # check defaults are ok 
/rh/path/to/initdb -D /rh/path/to/data-dir -k
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for version 11 a short peak into the script releveals this can be achieved by this command:

```
PGSETUP_INITDB_OPTIONS=-k /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
```

I know it is 1.5 years later but this was the first hit in DuckDuckGo :-)